# CSS issue with Responsive HOVER DIV

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm having a problem with the **mobile** version of a responsive website I'm building.

See that green "info" DIV that appears at the top left corner of the full-screen version of the site?
I need it to move down and live at the *bottom* of the screen - right above the footer DIV that has all the links - on the mobile version of the site.

Here's the full-screen version:

[image]

Here's the Mobile version:

[image]

Here's my CSS for the regular full-screen layout:

```
#productHoverDIV {
   z-index: 20;

   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;

   width: 300px;

   padding: 8px;
}
```

And here's the mobile rule:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 414px) {

  #productHoverDIV {
      z-index: 20;

      position: absolute;
      bottom: 40px; // that's the height of the FOOTER DIV below it

      width: 100%;

      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```

The issue is that even though I'm telling the `productHoverDIV` to be `40px` from the `bottom` on the mobile layout, it still keeps it's `top:10px` value from the regular CSS rule, and ends up covering almost the entire screen.
So I need to somehow cancel-out the `top` rule - or override it with a different value, except
I have no idea know what value to put from the `top` cause every mobile device has a different height.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should change it back to its default value, which is auto.
Removed the duplicated z-index and position values.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 414px) {

  #productHoverDIV {
      top: auto;
      bottom: 40px; 

      width: 100%;

      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```